# Implementing ElasticSearch custom filter for all queries

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration, matching, partial

I'm trying to upgrade from using ElasticSearch 0.90.3 to 2.0 and running into some issues.  The people who originally setup and configured ES are no longer available so I'm going about this with very little knowledge about how it works.

They configured ES 0.90.3 to use ElasticSearch-ServiceWrapper and Tire, beyond that there are only a couple small configuration changes.

For the most part, the upgrade went smooth, I replaced the setup information in the cap deploy process to now install ES 2.0 instead of 0.90.3 and the service is coming up, however, I cannot get the partial matching that was taking place before to work.  I need to setup a standard filter that applies to all searches that will search all fields using partial matches.  I've done tons of google searches and this is the closest I can come up with, but it still isn't returning partial matches.

```
index:
  settings:
    analysis:
      filter:
        autocomplete_filter:
          type: edge_ngram
          min_gram: 2
          max_gram: 32
      analyzer:
        autocomplete:
          type: custom
          tokenizer: standard
          filter: [ lowercase, autocomplete_filter ]

mappings:
  access_point_status:
    properties:
      text:
        type: string
        analyzer: autocomplete
        search_analyzer: standard
```

I was hoping to not need to replace Tire as that would make this upgrade much more involved, but if the problem lies within the queries and not the setup then I will go down that road.  This is a sample query that is not returning the desired results:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/access_point_status/_search?from=0&size=100&pretty' -d 
'{ "query":
   { "bool":
     { "must": [
       { "match":
         { "_all":
           { "query":
             "1925","type":"phrase_prefix"
           }
         }
       }
    ]}
   }
   ,"sort": [ { "name":"asc" } ]
   ,"filter": { "term": { "domain":"domain_1" } }
   ,"size":100,"from":0
}'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I've found most of the issues.  The indexes were being created by Tire and data_tables, using a different mapping.  This couldn't be overwritten once created.

I created these filters and then applied them to the fields,

```
index:
  analysis:
    filter:
      edge_ngram_filter:
        type: edge_ngram
        min_gram: 2
        max_gram: 32
        side: front
    analyzer:
      character_only:
        type: custom
        tokenizer: standard
        filter: [ lowercase, edge_ngram_filter ]
      special_character:
        type: custom
        tokenizer: keyword
        filter: [ lowercase, edge_ngram_filter ]
```

And I'm matching about 95% of the things I would hope too with

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/access_point_status/_search from=0&size=100&pretty' -d '
{
  "query":
  {
    "bool":
    {
      "must":[
      {
        "prefix":
        {
          "_all":"bsap-"
        }
      }]
    }
  },"sort":[
  {
    "name":"asc"
  }],"filter":
  {
    "term":
    {
      "domain":"domain_1"
    }
  },"size":100,"from":0
}'
```

The only thing I'm missing is getting special characters to match and uppercase characters are not matched.  I've tried several types of queries, query_string doesn't seem to match any partials.  Anyone have any thoughts on other queries?
I need to match things like mac addresses, ip's, and then combined text/number fields with -_,. as seperators.